# Automatically add files as embedded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, msbuild

I have a template service that uses [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to generate HTML for email sending.

I want to make it easy to add a new template to the project, meaning that I don't want to specify the file build action.

Is there a way where I still have the .cshtml file in my project with intellisense and etc. but it automatically will set their build action to Embedded Resource?

*Here is a example of my project structure*

[image: Example of solution]

Answer (score 0):

[Wildcard inclusions in C# project files](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/krome/wildcard-inclusions-in-c-project-files)

> However, we can use wildcards when specifying these files. Here is an example that includes all .py files from a folder (and all subfolders):
>
> EmbeddedResource Include="Python27\Lib\**\*.py" 
>
> Once you save the project file and reload it in Visual Studio, you will see that the Solution Explorer understands the wildcard and will populate with all files that match it. You can copy new .py files into the target directory and Solution Explorer will update accordingly (you need to click the “Refresh” button for this). And while it shows the results of the wildcard inclusion, it does not alter the entries in the project file unlike the behavior of the Add Files dialog.

Comment: I have tried something like this, but when I then add it to the solution and reload I had 2 of the same file listed in the solution explorer

Comment: Do they reference the same file, and are one of the duplicates an embedded resource and the other not an embedded resource?

Comment: It is the same file, one with build action = none and the other with build action = embeddedResource..

It happens when I use "Add new item" or "Add new existing" on the folder.